# Is the aws IAM user link accessible from anywhere across the globe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My IAM user link is not accessible from India and my office network in Japan. It is accessible from a pubic wifi in Japan though. Can someone please help.
Link is of the form: example.signin.aws.amazon.com/console

Comment: That is a public URL. You probably have a proxy or some internet filter that is blocking it.

Comment: Ya, I think so too. I get a 'Bad Gateway' or 'Connection Refused' error at times on my office network. But I remember accessing this link twice from my office before. How was that possible then? The cookie that AWS stores on the PC is very confusing in this case. Can someone throw some light?